# Correlation between DTS and time scale

Tags: javascript, time, scale, h.264

I am trying to make iso bmff from raw h264 byte stream for playing through javascript. I am getting data through custom transport container (Not any standard HLS or rtsp packet) where each packet contain a relative timestamp. For example:

**chunk1:**

Packet1 -- timestamp:100, payload: H264 raw data [Usually single NAL unit]

Packet2 -- timestamp:120, payload: h264 raw data

**chunk1:**

Packet1 -- timestamp:140, payload: H264 raw data

Packet2 -- timestamp:160, payload: h264 raw data

Since packet timestamp is the relative time in milliseconds so I am considering time scale value is 1000 and calculating DTS from difference of first packet and consecutive packet. For example,

DTS for 1st chunk: 0 [ 100 - 100]

DTS for 2nd chunk: 40 [140 - 100]

But problem is that it is working fine in firefox but chrome just got stuck after first frame.

What cause could be? Am I doing wrong with DTS or time scale?

Noted that I don't have any B frame, so my DTS and PTS value is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I was able to solve my problem. Basically there was nothing wrong with DTS value. I was using a modified version of mp4 generator that was the problem where duration part from trun box was removed.

I have got clue about this issue from my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402476/how-does-video-player-calculate-single-frame-duration) where szatmary mentioned about trun box duration.

Finally, I just copied mp4-generator from [hls repository](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/src/remux/mp4-generator.js) and it solved my issue. Now it is playing in chrome and safari as well.