# how does video player calculate single frame duration?

Tags: javascript, frame, h.264, frame-rate, mse

I am working on a project where I am muxing h264 raw stream into fmp4 so I can play it through MSE (Media source extension)

I am bit confused about frame duration. For example,

If I provide 30 frames and timescale is 1000, it plays for 1 second.

If I change timescale to 800, it plays for 2 seconds for the same 30 frames

If I change timescale to 500, it plays for 3 seconds for the same 30 frames

My question, how does the player calculate a single frame duration from timescale?

Comment: What is timescale? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate issue?

Comment: @guest271314 so I understand, time scale defines the number of time units that pass each second. for example, time scale of 60 measures sixtieths of a second

Comment: Sorry, I am getting data from live streaming so it is not possible to add any snippet.  My question is simple, why does player plays same 30 frames for different duration upon different timescale value? Noted that these are just first 30 frames and my based decoding times (dts) is 0, I am not adding any more frames after those.

Comment: Yes, you can create a live stream at stacksnippets. Can you link to a documentation or specification defining "timescale"?

Comment: Each frame has a duration encoded into the MP4. Changing the timescale doesn't change the durations of the frames.  So if each frame is duration 1, and time scale is 60, it will play at 60 fps. If you change the timescale, to 30, the frame durations are still 1, you cut the playback rate in half.

Comment: @szatmary but it is changing. I am getting data from live streaming and FPS is not static. Also my SPS have timing_info_present_flag is 0 that means there is no timescale and other timing information.  

So I am considering timescale 1000 while muxing h264 into fmp4. Now I am getting this issue. It is changing video duration whenever I change timescale although number of frames same

Comment: You are only changing the denominator (timescale). Not the numerator (sample_duration in the trun box). If you modify the denominator and not modify the numerator, you change the scale.

Comment: @szatmary you are absolutely correct. Thank you very much. Please post as answer, it should be accepted solution